# Retrieving the PID of a named process (which is consuming the most CPU)

Tags: process

I know that I can search processes via name via

```
ps -aux | grep <name>
```

Is there a way to use this to retrieve the `pid` of the named process that is *currently consuming the most CPU*? So for example if I search for the process name `godot` and there are 5 `godot` processes, can I retrieve the `pid` of the one which is consuming the most CPU?

Comment: Have you seen the output of the `top` command?

Answer (score 0):

use the `top` command:

`top -b -o -%CPU`

breaking it down:

```
top   ==> display processor activity
-b    ==> execute in bash mode
-o    ==> override command to change what we sort by
-%CPU ==> sorting parameter
```